# What is the best way to switch an existing Joomla site from http to https (SEO)

Tags: seo, .htaccess-configuration, ssl, https

What is the best way to switch an existing Joomla site from http to https (SSL), technically and also from an SEO approach.

1st, i had a rule in my htaccess but it was not perfect :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

So, i deleted the rule and discover that there was a simple "force SSL" option.

So i activated it and it seems to do the job.

But is it enough for SEO ?

Previously i was doing a redirect from non www to www like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.fr.fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Should i let this rule with force SSL or not ?

Answer (score 3):

Keep your .HTACCESS rule, but change it to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In your `configuration.php` file, make sure these two lines are set:

```
public $live_site = 'https://www.domain.fr';
public $force_ssl = '2';
```

Comment: I’ve tested you rule and it seems to work (redirect from non www to www + https). Thanks.

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I use this chunk of .htaccess settings in the custom redirects section of Joomla's default .htaccess:

```
# redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will work for any domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in .htaccess.  It first checks if http or https, then checks if www or non-www.  It will work for any domain and forces all four url variants to same one (in this case https://www.)

```
######### CLIENT-SPECIFIC #########
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
######### END CLIENT-SPECIFIC #########
```